# Herramienta para dibujar en LaTeX

Tags: latex

Llevo tiempo trabajando con LaTeX y en más de una ocasión tengo que elaborar algunos diagramas o dibujar formas geométricas. Entonces mi pregunta es:

Alguien conoce de alguna herramienta que facilite este trabajo. Es decir quizá algún **GUI** que permita generar el código latex para insertar a mi texto principal.

Comment: Esto no es una pregunta

Comment: Tienes toda la razón estado @AlvaroMontoro solo quería compartir la información.

Comment: Comprendo. Pero sería mejor si lo plantearas como una pregunta y tu mismo añadieses la respuesta. Así sí se ajustaría al formato de pregunta-respuesta del sitio y podrías encontrar con que otro usuario sugiere una alternativa que te acaba interesando más. Por ejemplo, la pregunta podría ser algo como "Estoy intentando hacer esto, esto y lo otro, y no sé cómo hacerlo", y luego te contestarías a ti mismo con "he encontrado esta herramienta que funciona genial por esto, esto y lo otro, y que se puede descargar/instalar haciendo esto"

Comment: Gracias por la indicación ya realice el cambio requerido. saludos!

Comment: Puedes probar Latex Draw, es una herramienta provista por la comunidad, para realizar gráficos para archivos de Latex, http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net

Comment: Gracias @JoelIbaceta, estoy revisando. mi consulta es, sabes si se puede compilar directamente a pdf, es decir sin antes tener que pasar por: latex > *.dvi > *.ps > *.pdf, estoy intentando pero no logro tener éxito.
gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como te lo indique en un comentario, puedes usar latex Draw para hacer los gráficos en documentos latex. http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net

Adicionalmente sobre la duda de si puedes generar un pdf desde el origen text, si se puede con `pdftex test1.tex`

Adicionalmente dispones de los siguientes comandos

```
tex test1.tex : convierte un archivo TeX a DVI  
pdftex test1.tex : convierte un archivo TeX a PDF  
latex test1.tex : convierte un archivo LaTeX a DVI 
pdflatex test1.tex : convierte un archivo LaTeX a PDF
```

Comment: Gracias @JoelIbaceta estoy haciendo un par de pruebas y te comento los resultados y/o modifico la pregunta inicial por si se me presenta algún problema. saludos!